# SSL certificate verification error on outgoing cluster traffic

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

#### Bug Description

My cluster uses Istio and one of service (java) which is deployed in mesh needs to connect to external resource `x.cmp.net/doc.pdf` with http and 443 port. This external resource using trusted wildcard cert (DigiCert) with subjects `*.cmp.net` and `cmp.net`.
When I try to use openssl to verify (from app container) ssl cert I'm getting **Google cert** (?? istio cert ?):

```
opt$ **openssl s_client -showcerts -connect x.cmp.net:443**
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.google.com
```

Application is written in java and when app tries to download resource getting:

```
No subject alternative DNS name matching shipjobmt.ista.net found.
```

My configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: internalnet
  namespace: ppct
spec:
  hosts:
    - x.cmp.net
    - y.cmp.net
    - z.cmp.net
  exportTo:
    - "."
  ports:
    - number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: xinternalnet
  namespace: ppct
spec:
  host: x.cmp.net
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: yinternalnet
  namespace: ppct
spec:
  host: y.cmp.net
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: zinternalnet
  namespace: ppct
spec:
  host: z.cmp.net
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
```

**I also have blocking mode on:**

```
kubectl get istiooperator installed-state -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.spec.meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode}'
REGISTRY_ONLY
```

#### Version

```
`istioctl version`
client version: 1.11.0
control plane version: 1.11.0
data plane version: 1.11.0 (65 proxies)


`kubectl version --short`
Client Version: v1.19.9
Server Version: v1.19.9
```

#### Additional Information

*No response*

Comment: Please include the actual error you mentioned in question title.

Comment: Im getting:
` No subject alternative DNS name matching x.cmp.net found.`

Comment: and also when try: openssl s_client -showcerts -connect x.cmp.net:443 getting not my cert:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be linked to double TLS (you can read more [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#double-tls)).
There are two possible solutions:

#### Solution 1

In `ServiceEntry` define protocol as HTTP with redirection to 443

```yaml
spec:
  hosts:
  - ...
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
    targetPort: 443
```

#### Solution 2

Disable TLS for outgoing traffic with `DestinationRule`

```yaml
trafficPolicy:
  tls:
    mode: DISABLE
```